# Can Require.js load scripts conditionally?

Tags: requirejs

Can i use Require.js to load scripts conditionally? 
For example if users browser is above IE9 than load a library. 
If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use conditional comments from html5boilerplate but there's also a conditional plugin for require.js https://github.com/guybedford/require-is

Comment: This Plugin is not compatible with r.js